# Comparing survey multiple choice survey questions response percentages between a subset's responses and the total collected responses

Tags: nonparametric, descriptive-statistics, proportion, survey-sampling

I have a survey composed of multiple choice questions. Several distinct branches of the same organization responded to the survey. I want to see if the distribution of answers from one branch is statistically different from the answers of all the branches combined (including the branch in question).

For example:

Q1: Do you feel staff safety has been increasing, declining, or staying the same?

a) Increasing

b) Declining

c) Staying the same

d) Uncertain

If Branch A answered 25% A, 30% B, 25% C, and 20% D, whereas the organization as a whole answered 50% A, 20% B, 20% C, and 10% D, is there a test I could use to validate that Branch A's difference from the Organization is statistically significant? I used percentages because the branches have different numbers of responses.

I am assuming my data in non-parametric. I thought about using a Chi Square test, but I don't know if that is appropriate given that I know my populations are not independent.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It may be easier to compare Branch 1 with all other branches (say 2 through 6) together, than to compare Branch 1 with the whole organization (including Branch 1 itself). Then you could use a chi-squared test on a $4 \times 6$ table of **counts** (not percentages), where the 4 rows are for responses a-d and the 6 columns are for the six branches. // Then if you find that responses are not independent of branches, you could use chi-sq. tests _ad hoc_ on sub-tables to see, for example, if Branches 1 and 5 are responsible for a major part of the effect.

Comment: I think I will do that, that should make for a better approach. Thank you for the help!